# When build the framework on Xcode 14 and fetch it via POD, I get an unsupported Swift architecture error. how to solve this?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcodebuild

Using Xcode 13,  I generated a framework to distribute via pod for integration, and it was successfully compiling for both device and simulator at the application side.

However, when I used the same xcodebuild command with xcode 14 to generate and distribute the framework, it threw a 'unsupported Swift architecture error' when  tried to integrate the framework via pod to application.

The framework is generated using the xcodebuild command.

```
Command line invocation:/Applications/Xcode_14.0.1.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild build -workspace <workSpacePath> -configuration Release -sdk iphonesimulator -scheme <Scheme_name> -derivedDataPath <Derived_path> CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO ENABLE_BITCODE=YES BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode SKIP_INSTALL=NO

Build settings from command line:
BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE = bitcode
CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED = NO
ENABLE_BITCODE = YES
SDKROOT = iphonesimulator16.0
SKIP_INSTALL = NO`
```